# What is the indirect meaning to this dialogue in Baywatch (2017)?

Tags: meaning

Mitch said this dialogue to Victoria leeds.

> Mitch: I heard you were a head-turner. What an understatement that is.
>
> Victoria: And I heard you were a charmer. Guess that's an
>   understatement, too.

Does it means Victoria is not beautiful in Mitch dialogue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that Victoria is so attractive that people turn their heads to look at her. And Mitch is saying that, even though he had heard that Victoria was attractive it does not state strongly enough how beautiful she is.